# How to save data in Firestore local cache?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I discovered a very useful function named [get(Source source)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#get(com.google.firebase.firestore.Source)). If I pass CACHE, I can get data only from cache. But how about set(Source source)? I cannot find something similar. I need to save data locally and push it to the server only when needed. How to solve this? Or any other alternatives? Thanks

Comment: Why -1? I really need to solve this :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not supported by the Firestore client libraries.  Then only kind of writes you can perform will **always** be synchronized to the server at the earliest opportunity.  There is no operation that lets you write, then decide to synchronize later.

What you should do instead is write data to some other local storage (perhaps a database), then write those records to Firestore when you're ready.

Comment: It's think it is "not" supported. Thanks for the answer. I'll use Room for that.